# Makefile always recompiles

Tags: c++, makefile

i am having a hard time with the Makefile below. It always recompiles because it is looking for the objects in "source/" instead of "objects/".

Since i did not write that Makefile and don't know what all those options mean i can't figure out how to tell it to look for the objects in the correct folder.

```
TITLE =example_title

SRC_DIR = source/
OBJ_DIR = objects/
OUTDIR = build/

SRC := $(wildcard **/*.cpp)
OBJ := $(patsubst source/%.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))
FP_OBJ := $(patsubst %,objects/%,$(OBJ))
LIB = $(wildcard *.a) $(wildcard **/*.a)

CC =g++
LD =g++
CC_FLAGS = -m32 -c -Wall -g -o 
EXECUTABLE = $(TITLE)
LD_FLAGS = -m32 -L/usr/lib32 -o $(OUTDIR)$(EXECUTABLE)

$(OUTDIR)$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJ)
  $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) $(FP_OBJ) $(LIB)

$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
  $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS)$(OBJ_DIR)$@ $(SRC_DIR)$*.cpp 

$(TITLE).tar.gz : **/*.h **/*.cpp Makefile **/*.txt
  tar -czf $@ Makefile **/*.h **/*.cpp **/*.txt

dist: $(TITLE).tar.gz

all : $(OUTDIR)$(EXECUTABLE)

clean : 
  rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)*.o
  rm -f $(OUTDIR)$(EXECUTABLE) $(TITLE).tar.gz
```

Comment: How will correcting _your_ makefile help others in the future? This is a Q&A resource not a helpdesk...

Comment: I get that this might be an annoying question but i was provided with this makefile for an assignment for university and i did not know a more suitable or quicker place where to get a proper answer. However Beta also included an explanation so perhaps this will help others in the future as well. Before asking i also tried to fix it myself but without knowledge in creating such Makefiles i did not get anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(OUTDIR)$(EXECUTABLE) : $(FP_OBJ)
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) $^ $(LIB)

$(FP_OBJ) : $(OBJ_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $@ $<
```

The basic problem was here:

```
$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS)$(OBJ_DIR)$@ $(SRC_DIR)$*.cpp
```

Apart from the fact that `$(OBJ) : $(SRC)` makes *each* object depend on *all* sources, this rule promises `foo.o` and delivers `objects/foo.o`. So every time through, Make saw that there was no `foo.o`, and duly tried to rebuild it and the executable that required it.

There are other problems with this makefile, like the sloppy wildcards and the obnoxious practice of including slashes in the directory names, but they're not so serious.

Comment: Beat me too it I was just writing a comment explaining what your fix did. Though doesn't that static pattern rule need suffixes on the target/prereq patterns to work (since the stem isn't going to be the same on both sides)?